# Why are my answer's decimals incorrect in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am currently busy with a question that requires for one to solve Ax = b using Jacobi method where the function created must return x and the 2 norm of x.

The question states that when b is inputted as

```
b = [71; 42;-11;-37;-61; 52]
T = 2
N = 2
```

The answer that i am supposed to get is `x = [2.73186728; 1.44791667; 0.62885802; 6.32696759; 6.390625; 3.33012821]` and the norm of x `10.0953`

However I get `x = [ 3.07507642;  0.58675203; -0.64849988;  5.33343053; 6.66765397; 4.16161712]` and the 2 norm of x `10.0221`

I am trying to find where the error in my code is but finding it difficult...below is my code

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import array
from scipy.linalg import solve


def jacobi(A, b, x0, N):

    n = A.shape[0]
    x = x0.copy()
    k = 0
    x_prev= x0.copy()

    for i in range(0, n):
        subs = 0.0
        for j in range(0, n):
            if i != j:
                subs += np.matrix(A[i,j])*np.matrix(x_prev[j])

        x[i] = (b[i]-subs)/np.matrix(A[i,i])

    k += 1

    return(x)


A = array([[18, 1, 4, 3, -1, 2],
           [2, 12, -1, 7, -2, 1],
           [-1, 1, -9, 2, -5, 2],
           [2, 4, 1, -12, 1, 3],
           [1, 3, 1, 7, -16, 1],
           [-2, 1, 7, -1, 2, 13]]) 

x0 = array([[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]])

elements_of_b_and_N = list(map(float, input().split(' ')))
b_and_N = array(elements_of_b_and_N).reshape(A.shape[0]+1, )
b = b_and_N[:A.shape[0]]
N = b_and_N[A.shape[0]]

x = jacobi(A, b, x0, N)
print((solve(A, b)))
print(round(norm((solve(A,b)), 2), 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you compute the true value ?

> The question states that when b is inputted as b = [71;
>   42;-11;-37;-61; 52]T and N = 2, the answer that i am supposed to get
>   is x = [2.73186728; 1.44791667; 0.62885802; 6.32696759; 6.390625;
>   3.33012821] and the norm of x 10.0953

When I execute :

```
x0 = array([[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]], dtype=float)
A = array([[18, 1, 4, 3, -1, 2],
       [2, 12, -1, 7, -2, 1],
       [-1, 1, -9, 2, -5, 2],
       [2, 4, 1, -12, 1, 3],
       [1, 3, 1, 7, -16, 1],
       [-2, 1, 7, -1, 2, 13]])
b = array([[71], [42], [-11], [-37], [-61], [52]], dtype=float)

print(solve(A, b))
```

I get :

```
[[ 3.07507642]
[ 0.58675203]
[-0.64849988]
[ 5.33343053]
[ 6.66765397]
[ 4.16161712]]
```

As you do with Jacobi.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is such a simpler  way of writing it. Thank you!